# How to delete records from a table if they don't meet a condition in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, company and company_name. company contains the columns: company_id(primary key) and company_name, while company_name contains the columns: company_id(foreign key from company table), company_name, and is_proper. Currently, the company table is filled with several records, but I wish to only keep company_names that appear in both tables and records where is_proper = 1.

Example company Table

```
company_id    company_name
1             Apple
2             Apple Inc.
3             Fcebook   
4             Facebook
5             Facebook Inc. 
6             Google Inc.
```

Example company_name Table:

```
company_id    company_name    is_proper
2             Apple           0
2             Apple Inc.      1
5             Fcebook         0
5             Facebook        0
5             Facebook Inc.   1
6             Google Inc.     1
```

What I want company Table to look like:

```
company_id    company_name
2             Apple Inc.
5             Facebook Inc.
6             Google Inc.
```

If someone knows a SQL command to do this, it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which table do you want to delete rows?

Comment: I want to delete rows from the company table. @forpas

Comment: This is what I thought, but good to clarify. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete c from company c
where not exists (
  select 1 from company_name 
  where company_id = c.company_id and company_name = c.company_name and is_proper = 1
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be12a3d961736c72b9bd9092a1773565).
Results:

```
> company_id | company_name 
> ---------: | :------------
>          2 | Apple Inc.   
>          5 | Facebook Inc.
>          6 | Google Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

> MySQL

```
delete from company_table ct where 
ct.company_name in (select cn.`company_name` from company_name cn where is_proper = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but wouldn't this delete the records where is_proper = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the tables and add a condition `is_proper = 0`.

```
delete from
company_name as cn
join company as c
    on cn.company_name = c.company_name
    and cn.is_proper = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can do this MySQL

DELETE FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_ID NOT IN (SELECT COMPANY_ID FROM COMPANY_NAME WHERE IS_PROPER=1);;

Comment: Why did you revert the edit? There's no reason for the title to be bold, plus having the query in a code block looks nicer.

Answer (score 0):

For this operation, you can try and use the JOIN and WHICH operations supposing its in SQL.

A sample syntax for this is:

```
DELETE DeletingFromTable
     FROM DeletingFromTable INNER JOIN CriteriaTable
     ON DeletingFromTable.field_id = CriteriaTable.id
     WHERE CriteriaTable.criteria = "value";
```

**To delete records based on another table:**

```
    Delete From Table1 a,Table2 b where a.id=b.id

        Or

          DELETE FROM Table1
        WHERE Table1.id IN (SELECT Table2.id FROM Table2)

      Or

            DELETE Table1
         FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```